# Where can I find good documentation about memories?

Tags: microcontroller, memory, flash, ram, documentation

I'm learning about the different kinds and functionalities of electronic memories (i.e. RAM, flash, etc) but I'm a little confused because all the sources show something different and I don't know which of them is correct.

What manuals or documents are accurate?

Documentation about micro-controllers would be good too. The purpose of this is only learning. I'm not looking for documentation about a specific device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDN has a sub-site dedicated to memory.

[Professor Memory](http://www.professormemory.edn.com/) may be the right place for you to learn about memory and about newer technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic information about different types of memory. Nice place to get started:

http://computer.howstuffworks.com/computer-memory.htm

Once you have an idea of the different types of memory out there, each one's purpose etc., then you can go into the detailed architecture.

Basic information about Microcontrollers, also to get you started:
http://www.howstuffworks.com/microcontroller.htm

Comment: The memory options computer.howstuffworks.com has seem to be more directed at a user of a computer, not someone whom is going to be using microcontrollers.